# Rename an image file if already exists on the server PHP

Tags: php, image, upload, rename

I'd like to add suffix to the filename if the file already exists on the server.

For example: if the file image.jpg exists on the server the new file to be renamed to image_1.jpg, image_2.jpg etc.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
$max_file_size = 1024*100000; // 100000kb
    $valid_exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
    // thumbnail sizes
    $sizes = array(250 => 150);

    if (isset($_FILES["$fileime"])) {
      if( $_FILES["$fileime"]['size'] < $max_file_size ){
        // get file extension
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["$fileime"]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts)) {
          /* resize image */
          foreach ($sizes as $width => $height) {
            /* Get original image x y*/
                  list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES["$fileime"]["tmp_name"]);
                  /* calculate new image size with ratio */
                  $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
                  $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
                  $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
                  $w = ceil($width / $ratio);
                  /* new file name */
                  $path = '../thumbs/'.$_FILES["$fileime"]['name'];
                  /* read binary data from image file */
                  $imgString = file_get_contents($_FILES["$fileime"]['tmp_name']);
                  /* create image from string */
                  $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
                  $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                  imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
                    0, 0,
                    $x, 0,
                    $width, $height,
                    $w, $h);
```

Comment: Do you have any specific problem? You say what you need to do, but it would better for the sake of clarity to outline, what is the exact issue, or what points are not clear to you, so that you can get a specific help.

Comment: I just need any help how to modify the code so that new uploaded files does not overwrite the existing ones with the same filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the timestamp at the end of your file name?

```
$max_file_size = 1024*100000; // 100000kb
    $valid_exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
    // thumbnail sizes
    $sizes = array(250 => 150);

    if (isset($_FILES["$fileime"])) {
      if( $_FILES["$fileime"]['size'] < $max_file_size ){
        // get file extension
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["$fileime"]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts)) {
          /* resize image */
          foreach ($sizes as $width => $height) {
            /* Get original image x y*/
                  list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES["$fileime"]["tmp_name"]);
                  /* calculate new image size with ratio */
                  $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
                  $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
                  $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
                  $w = ceil($width / $ratio);
                  /* new file name */
                  $filename_array = explode('.', $_FILES["$fileime"]['name']);
                  $extension = array_pop($filename_array);
                  $new_name = implode('.',$filename_array).'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
                  $path = '../thumbs/'.$new_name;
                  /* read binary data from image file */
                  $imgString = file_get_contents($_FILES["$fileime"]['tmp_name']);
                  /* create image from string */
                  $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
                  $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                  imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
                    0, 0,
                    $x, 0,
                    $width, $height,
                    $w, $h);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm beginner in PHP. I understand that I should use $timestamp = time(); Would you advise me where I should implement it in the code above?